# Community detail page not able to see

Tags: community

I've created a only community in production and not site. I've configure the community perfectly as required.

Now I've to set the Custom Vf page Active site home page for community. 
But to set this I'm unable to see detail page of community.

The below screeshot in sandbox. 
[image]

The above page is unabale to see in production to configure.

So how can i configure and set pages for community

Comment: Is the community published or still in preview?

Comment: @DaveHumm yes. Community is published

Comment: Did you get eany error message  ? . Did you added the page in the public access setting config[Button].

Comment: @bharath thats the my queston, I'm not able to see above screenshot page   in production. so how can i configure pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to follows the below steps to go to detail page of community.

Setup--> All Communities --> workspace --> Administrator --> Pages --> Go to Force.com

After click on `Go to Force.com`, you will redirect to detail page of community where you can configure pages.